# Android SQLite more than one WHERE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, where-clause

I have been looking for it but I am unable to find what I need. I have a SQLite table in  android, and I would like to know how the rawquery would be for more than one WHERE clause. I mean, I want to know all the records of a table and all columns of those WHERE the value of two colums are 1 for example.

How could I do this?

I've tried:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
        + " WHERE " + KEY_ONE + " = " + String.valueOf(var1)
        + " AND WHERE " + KEY_TWO + " = " + String.valueOf(Var2);

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

But it isn't working..

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: You have to write `WHERE` clause only once. then you can use `AND` to check second,third,....conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second `WHERE`:

```
+ " AND " + KEY_TWO + " = " + String.valueOf(Var2);
```

Also note that strings must be enclosed in apostrophes:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
    + " WHERE " + KEY_ONE + " = '" + String.valueOf(var1)
    + "' AND " + KEY_TWO + " = '" + String.valueOf(Var2) + "'";
```

Even better if you use this enhanced syntax:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
    + " WHERE " + KEY_ONE + " = ? AND " + KEY_TWO + " = ?";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(var1), String.valueOf(var2)});
```

Comment: Why is the second syntax better than the first one? Thanks

Comment: For several reasons: 1 - because it's not SQL-Injection prone. 2 - because it handles the proper datatypes for you (see, in the second syntax I removed the apostrophes surrounding the strings).

Answer (score 1):

Please try as follows and remove the second WHERE clause

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
        + " WHERE " + KEY_ONE + " = " + String.valueOf(var1)
        + " AND " + KEY_TWO + " = " + String.valueOf(Var2);

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```